# Double integral using integral2, too many input arguments

Tags: matlab

This is the code:

```
for Y=0:0.01:N,
    eta(round(1+Y*100))=((i*alpha*lambda)^(1/3))*Y+eta0;
    V2(round(1+Y*100))=((i*alpha*lambda)^(-2/3))*q*integral2(@(n) airy(n),eta0,eta,eta0,eta);
end
```

What's going on?

```
Error using profiles>@(n)airy(n)
Too many input arguments.
```

Comment: Interesting. I'd say it has "too few input argumets"

Comment: The point is, how do I modify a predefined MATLAB function of one variable so as to integrate it twice via integral2?

Comment: You need a bi-variable function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want to calculate the volume under a plane `z = f(x, y)`, which is the goal of `integral2`. You want to calculate the integral of the integral:

```
integral(@(n) integral(@(x) airy(x), xMin, n), xMin, xMax, 'ArrayValued', true)
```

Note that we need to add `'ArrayValued' = true` for the outer integral, because the inner integral does not allow a vectorised evaluation for its upper limit.

This can be optimised (~10x faster) using `integral2`:

```
integral2(@(x, y) airy(y), xMin, xMax, xMin, @(x) x)
```

You can interpret it as follows: the inner integral is calculated by integrating over the `y` axis up to `y = x` and the outer integral is calculated by integrating the result of the `y` integration.

**Validation of provided method**

One can validate the method with the following test function:

```
airy = @(n) n; % linear test function
xMin = 0;
xMax = 10;
```

The second integral is: `n^3/6 = 166.6667`, which is indeed the result of both methods.